# Use of getters in toObject() function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I am starting to go through a node js-express application code for learning purpose. Encountered the following line and not sure about the use of getters and virtuals in the following line.

```
 var pgmsDbObj = chnnlList[chnnlIndex]
 var pgmsObj = pgmsDbObj.toObject({ getters: true, virtuals: false })
```

I searched for toObject function and it's a function to create an object map from a list of keys and a single values. So what's the use of getters and virtuals here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case it is   a `Mongoose` method to convert document into a plain javascript object, ready for storage in MongoDB.

For Reference Look [Here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject)